# How do I learn opponent ship details?

Tags: eve-online

While flying and working on PvE missions (usually security) that I can barely pass, I often dream to know what ship my opponent is flying and what is the best weapon to kill him.

Is there any way to determine what armor/shield the opponent ship has? What about the weapon?

Comment: Do you mean the NPCs you see on missions or other players?

Comment: Yes, it's unclear whether you're talking about "mission" opponents or other players.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In missions, every NPC has a set damage type that they deal and are weak against. The Eve University [Wiki](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/NPC_Damage_Types) has a full list of the various types.

Take Sansha for example (common in Amarr space). They deal EM/Thermal (laser) damage, so it's best to tank against that. They also happen to be weak against EM/Thermal, so lasers do the best damage (or alternatively, EM missiles or drones).

Against players is a different ballgame and there's no easy way to tell where the weak points are.

Comment: As I stumbled over this page and since the EVE Online Wiki has been disbanded, the currently best resource for this I consider to be the EVE Uni Wiki, with its article here http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/NPC_Damage_Types

Comment: I have always used this cheat sheet, it is full of awesome info: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6781003/EvE/Quick%20Reference%20Sheet%20by%20Korgan%20Nailo.pdf

Answer (score 5):

It has been quite some time since I have played EVE Online, so please view my answer framed with that disclaimer.

Since you mention missions, you might want to make yourself aware of the EVE Survival Guide: http://eve-survival.org/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage.  In my mission running days this was an indispensable guide for making my way though missions.  It should also be mentioned that there are only a limited number of missions at each mission hub, and you will start to see a lot of repeats over time.

If you are referring to PVP, you can always fit a [ship scanner module](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Ship_Scanner_I), but I personally would recommend against it unless flying a specialized ship as a part of a fleet.  In most cases when flying solo, the ship scanner will take up valuable CPU and PowerGrid resources that can be used better used for other ship modules.  Further, when you consider that a ship scanner will rarely give you an entire list of a ship's modules, the benefit is rarely outpaced by the fitting cost.

Comment: I almost never see the ship scanner fit except to neuting battleships (since it gives the cap level of your target so you know when they're capped out) or to detect obvious bait when attempting ganks for the reasons you describe.

Comment: I ran one for a bit on an alt in scan frigate, but really only because, at that character's skill level, I couldn't fit anything useful.  Otherwise, you are exactly right.  There's little other reason to fit a scanner.

Comment: Sadly, eve-survival is no longer available, however it can be seen in the internet archive or waybackmachine - google for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to find out the fitting of the NPC ships you are fighting:

There are some online databases where you can get the configuration of many NPC ships. Note that CCP has stopped publishing this information, so you won't find any new ships. But its still works great for most missions.

- [Chruker Inventory Search](http://games.chruker.dk/eve_online/inventory_search.php). Example: [Gist Warlord](http://games.chruker.dk/eve_online/item.php?type_id=16926)
- [EVE Info NPC Ships](https://eveinfo.com/npcships)

Answer (score -1):

There is a new tool for doing exactly this: [EVE Fast Fitting Assessment](https://github.com/rischwa/eve-fast-fitting-assessment).

> EVE Fast Fitting Assessment (FFA) is a Windows desktop application to quickly assess the stats of fittings found on killmails... EVE Fast Fitting Assessment was designed to be useful for EVE players and at the same time also provide insight into a multitude of CREST endpoints for (future) EVE 3rd party developers.

The repo readme contains installation and usage instructions.